# What does $Y = \min(X, 0)$ stand for in calculating expected value for random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, density-function

> The random variable $X$ has a distribution in $\mathbb{R}$ with density $$g(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if } x < 0 \\ e^{-x} & \text{if } x \geq 0\end{cases}$$ Calculate the expected value of the random variable $ Y = \min(X, 3)$. 
>  **Hint**: The density of the random variable $Y$ is the same as that of the variable $X$.

---

I know the expected value for $X$ is:
$$E(X) = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty }^{\infty}xf(x)dx = \int_{0 }^{\infty}xe^{-x}dx = \begin{bmatrix} -xe^{-x}+\int e^{-x}dx \end{bmatrix}_{0}^{\infty} =  \begin{bmatrix} -xe^{-x}-e^{-x} \end{bmatrix}_{0}^{1} = 1  $$ 
But I don't understand what $Y = \min(X, 3)$ means, is it an interval $(0, 3)$ or maybe just $0$? The minimal value of $g(x)$ for an argument from the range of $<0,3>$ is $0$. 
Is this the answer?:
$$ E(Y) =  \displaystyle \int_{0}^{3}xe^{-x}dx = \begin{bmatrix} -xe^{-x}+\int e^{-x}dx \end{bmatrix}_{0}^{3} = 1 - 4e^{-3}$$

Comment: $\min(X,3) = \begin{cases} X & \text{if $X \le 3$} \\ 3 & \text{if $X > 3$}\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $X\sim\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $c>0$ with $Y=X\wedge c$. then $Y$ has a mixture distribution with
$$
\mathbb P(Y=c) = \mathbb P(X\geqslant c) = 1-\int_0^c \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\ \mathsf dt= e^{-\lambda c}.
$$
and for $0<t<c$,$$
\mathbb P(X\leqslant t) = \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\ \mathsf dx = 1-e^{-\lambda t},
$$
so that
$$
F_Y(t) := \mathbb P(X\leqslant t) = (1-e^{-\lambda t})\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,c)}(t) + e^{-\lambda c}\cdot\mathsf 1_{[c,\infty)}(t),\ t\geqslant 0.
$$
The expected value would then be
$$
\int_0^\infty (1-F_Y(t))\ \mathsf dt = \int_0^ce^{-\lambda x}\ \mathsf dx + c\cdot\mathbb P(X=c) = \frac1\lambda\left(1-e^{-\lambda c}\right).
$$